# Is that only an error with calling gets?

Tags: c, pointers, semantics

We got this task, and would like to know if we overlooked something in our solution:

> There is a problem with the following code fragment. It will compile, but there is an important semantic problem, which will cause the code to behave differently than expected. Identify the problem and a solution to this problem.

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    char * s = malloc(82 * sizeof(char)); 
    if(s==NULL) 
    {  
        perror("failed to allocate memory");  
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    } 
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin); 
    if(s[strlen(s)-1] != '\n') 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: you entered too much input"); 
        free(s); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    } 
    free(s); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

We think the error is with the `fgets` function, as it will read in everything including the null terminating character. So we believe that there is the potential to write to a character to that has not been `malloc`'d. So we believe that the line `fget(s,sizeof(s)-1, stdin);` would be the fix.
Are we right? Or are there more / other errors?

Comment: you say "behave differently than expected". do you know what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Reads like a homework assignment that's been cut & pasted to me.

Comment: @duffmo not a homework problem it is a past exam question for advanced programming techniques at RMIT university. But it was definitely cut and pasted from the past paper. I can send you the whole past exam paper if you are interested.

Comment: @Woodrow i have no idea what the expected behavior is. I bought this up with the lecturer saying this question is ambiguous without context. Though its interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof( s )` <=> `sizeof( char * )`, and that's not what you want.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. I didnt realise that size of a malloc'd address would only return the size of the type that has been malloc'd and not the entire allocated memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(s)` is most likely going to be 4 or 8. In any case, it's not going to be 82.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. I didnt realise that size of a malloc'd address would only return the size of the type that has been malloc'd and not the entire allocated memory. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf: You do not malloc an address, you malloc a block of memory. Just keep the concept pointer and pointee strictly separate.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a long code, so let's get them all:

1. There are no includes. You need:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h> // perror fgets fprintf
   #include <stdlib.h> // malloc free EXIT_FAILURE EXIT_SUCCESS
   #include <string.h> // strlen
   ```
2. Avoid magic constants. If you need some constant, define it in one place (with a telling name), and then always refer to that.

   ```
   #define MY_MAX_STRING_SIZE 82
   // Not length, that would be one less due to the terminator
   ```
3. Style-point: A `char` will always be exactly one `char` big.

   ```
   char * s = malloc(MY_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
   ```
4. Always check the return-value of `fgets`. On failure, that's `NULL`.
5. The `sizeof`-operator returns the size of its operand, not the size of a buffer it might point at. Use the constant from above:

   ```
   if(!fgets(s, MY_MAX_STRING_SIZE, stdin)) {
       perror("failed to read from stdin");
       free(s);
       return EXIT_FAILURE; 
   };
   ```
6. Those three lines are equivalent for ending `main`:

   ```
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   return 0;
   // C99+
   ```
7. Why do you use dynamic allocation at all? An automatic array would be safer, easier and more performant:

   ```
   // includes...
   int main() {
       char s[82];
       if(!fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)) {
           perror("failed to read from stdin"); 
           return EXIT_FAILURE; 
       };
       if(s[strlen(s)-1] != '\n') 
       { 
           fprintf(stderr, "Error: you entered too much input"); 
           return EXIT_FAILURE; 
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. For this question i believe our lecturer wants us to understand that sizeof returns the size of type, not the size of the memory allocated.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf: I'm sure your lecturer will be delighted when you learned all the rest too. ;-)

Comment: im sure he will be. I just prefer to clarify my understanding with the people in the know. Which is why i posted what i thought was the solution to the semantics at the base of the problem. Which i got wrong haha.

Comment: BTW: There were two bugs (`fgets` and `sizeof`), one ellision (the includes), one severe coding standard violation (magic number), one (probably due to contrived example) dynamic allocation which should be automatic and a few side-notes.